# Regex: Match all double quotes in string and add comma

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I need to turn a string like this:

```
' query: "help me" distance: "25" count: "50" '
```

into a javascript object or json string that looks like this:

```
'{ query: "help me", distance: "25", count: "50" }'
```

Comment: How are you constructing the original string? It's probably easier to do it then and not have a tough regex later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
var query = ' query: "help me" distance: "25" count: "50"';
query = '{' + query.replace(/"(?=\s)/g, '",') + '}';
console.log(query);
```

With that lookahead expression I just put comma after all the double quotation marks that are followed by whitespace symbol.

Having said that, I'd strongly suggest reconsidering the method of constructing your params: somehow I feel you could get away with simple `JSON.stringify`-ing the params. It will be much more bulletproof - and easier to parse too.

Comment: As of backbone.js 0.9.9 doesn't support normal params in the router history. My solution is to construct params like this `/search/query:%20"face"%20distance:%20"25"`